# Why do dist upgrades still have to freeze and ask questions?

Tags: upgrade

I left my dist upgrade (from Netbook Edition 10.04 to 10.10) running overnight and I wake up to see it frozen at some ridiculous question about replacing a config file.  Why can't they still get this right?  Don't pause and ask questions!!

Isn't Ubuntu supposed to be for average usrs?  How is an average user supposed to know the "right" answer to such a question?

If the developers really feel they have to offer this flexibility, at least ask a question at the **beginning** of the upgrade like "when there are config file conflicts, should we stop and ask you about it or just make our best guess?"

Comment: A more constructive thing to do is to figure out if it's a bug or not and report it. By default if you edit a config file we do default to asking you on upgrade.

Comment: -1 This is more a complain than a question. Next time please post your question, read the answers, late if you feel appropriate file a bug report at launchpad.

Comment: This is not a question... report a bug.

Comment: Here is [the relevant bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/352240) (Importance: Wishlist, nobody is working on this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would not be practical to do at the beginning of the process as in order to know which packages will ask a question, it has to unpack and evaluate their upgrade.

There is the possibility of doing this at the end, or defaulting to "keep config" but this adds complexities to the installer.

The installers are scriptable. Some have interactive parts that (if there) you would still want to run... Again, there might be the possibility of moving this to the end of the process.

The problem with both these ideas is they require changing significant portions of the dpkg system. As a result packages might need to be built differently for it to work and oh look, we're incompatible with debian! This is infinitely more of a problem than asking a few questions through the upgrade process.

Comment: Ubuntu could of course work together with dpkg-developers (or pay one) to work on such a feature (collecting and postponing the questions to the end) that would be acceptable for inclusion in the upstream dpkg.

Comment: The most valid answer here is "incompatibility with debian"
An upgrade is a tedious long proces, and changes in config files are there for a reason. I would prefer to leave them as they are and have a report afterwards on not upgraded config files and incompatible options in config files.
It is rather a request than a question, yes